# How to apply multiple query in android firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**This is My Firebase database structure**
[image: this my firbase database structure]

i want to get data like

**category** = "cat" and **level** = "1"

**Here is my code**

```
 Query query = firebaseReference.orderByChild("category").equalTo("cat1").limitToFirst(20);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                UTILS.Log.e(TAG, "List Of User Count " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    //FCreateUSer modelRegister = dataSnapshot1.getValue(FCreateUSer.class);
                    UTILS.Log.e(TAG, "User Email :" + dataSnapshot1.child("question").getValue());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
```

it's wrok but how to use two condition in firbase i try two `orderByChild`  but it's give error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls!**

Comment: A Firebase Database query can only use a single `orderBy` call. You may be able to combine the values into a single property to achieve your use-case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this video (it's in JavaScript, but it exactly solves your problem): https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=612

Basically, you need to structure your data for your queries. In OP example Question will have field like `category_level: "cat_1"`. Then you can perform query `equalTo("cat_1")`. You can leave out both `category` and `level` fields if you need it for other queries (but you will need to handle duplication in that case).

If you know that your number of items is small, simplest solution is to just pull all `category=cat` and filter `level=1` items.

Comment: Thnx i will check video

Comment: nope i can't filter bcz in category more than 2000 recode so can't filter level = 1

Comment: While the video may address OPs question, your answer should include the minimal answer too.

Comment: Ok, i added it.

Comment: from this video i  already  done that you say and it's work and  thanx for help i m going to vote up and accepting your answer

Comment: @AndroidGeeks how did you applied that? can you share code?

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan i follow  Guidn Way, we can't apply multiple query in firebase