# How to use Multiple query firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i want to get user name that have blood group and city have same send by the user......i want user om that basis???

Now I want to filter the result for "BloodGroup"=="some thing" AND "city"=="any city"
to get user that have both bloodgroup and city

This is my data structure.

[image: my structure is]

Comment: visit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262660/how-to-apply-multiple-query-in-android-firbase

Comment: how would we get specific user on these two things bloodgroup and city